# Sum of dictionary values in python and coming up with "unsupported operand type" error

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
result = {'kid': ['$6.00', '$159.00', '$10.00'], 
          'entertainment': ['$2.40', '$3.10', '$30.37', '$40.15'], 
          'food': ['$5.04', '$8.00', '$160.15'], 
          ... }
```

I'm trying to write code that will add up the amounts of each value and print it next to the corresponding key, with a result such as this:

```
['kid': '$175', 'entertainment': '$76.02', 'food': '$249.21', .... etc.]
```

I've used the following code and variations of it, trying to get a sum of the values.

```
sumCat={}

for k, v in result.items():
    sumCat[k] = sum(v)

print(sumCat)
```

But I always get this error message:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I don't understand the message.

Comment: because `'$175'` is string, not number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying add strings together -- notice how the prices in your original answer are in quotes and have the `$` symbol, they're not just numbers!

The way to solve this is to account for that in your adding. I'd avoid using the `sum` method here as it's not really designed for handling input like this. Here's one way to do it:

```
sumCat={}

for k, v in result.items():
    summed_vals = 0
    for price in v:
        if '-' in price:
            # takes into account the dollar sign/negative sign
            summed_vals -= float(price[2:])         
        else:
            summed_vals += float(price[1:]) # takes into account the dollar sign
    sumCat[k] = format(summed_vals, '.2f') # rounds to nearest cent

print(sumCat)

#output
{'food': '173.19', 'kid': '175.00', 'entertainment': '76.02'}
```

Comment: I just realized that some of the values in my dictionary (or "price") are negative numbers. Is there a way to "sum" together positive and negative values?

Comment: Does the value look like ‘-$5.00’ or ‘$-5.00’?

Comment: Value looks like '-$5.00'

Comment: Updated answer to incorporate negative sign. Also, if this answered your question please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 5):

You're using "sum" on a list of strings.  You have to convert each to an numeric value, add *those* and then convert to the form you want.

I suggest that you deal with only the values; leave the `$` for output formatting.

Comment: Of course! I knew the answer to the puzzle was something like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {'kid': ['$6.00', '$159.00', '$10.00'], 'entertainment': ['$2.40', '$3.10', '$30.37', '$40.15'], 'food': ['$5.04', '$8.00', '$160.15']}
final_result = {a:"$ {}".format(round(sum(float(i[1:]) for i in b), 2)) for a, b in result.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'kid': '$ 175.0', 'entertainment': '$ 76.02', 'food': '$ 173.19'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with `str.strip` and `float` to convert your strings into numeric data which can be summed.

```
d = {'kid': ['$6.00', '$159.00', '$10.00'], 
     'entertainment': ['$2.40', '$3.10', '$30.37', '$40.15'], 
     'food': ['$5.04', '$8.00', '$160.15']}

res = {k: sum(map(float, (i.strip('$') for i in v))) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'entertainment': 76.02,
 'food': 173.19,
 'kid': 175.0}
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. What if I want to rewrite the new amounts to a new CSV WITH the $? What's the opposite of strip?

Comment: Look up `str.format` for how you can do the reverse.

Comment: Gotcha! Also, do you know how I can take into account negative figures in getting the sum of the values? I'm actually working on a larger csv file and I just realized that some of the values are negative numbers. And I'm not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: Negative numbers are also converted to `float` and summed without issues. If you need special treatment, I suggest you ask as a separately question.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `$` and use just `map()`.

```
result = {'kid': ['6.00', '159.00'], 'entertainment': ['2.40','40.15']}
sumCat={}

for k, v in result.items():
   sumCat[k] = sum(map(float,v))

print(sumCat)
```